# How to separate ODI grips from lock on clips?

Tags: mountain-bike, grips

Are there any tricks to separating ODI grips from lock on clips. I'm worried that if I go at them with a screwdriver I'll end up damaging the clips.

Comment: Do you have any pictures of this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put a flat blade screw driver into the bar whole with the blade between the clip and the grip and gently pry it away from the grip by leveraging on the opposite side of the clip, it should pop off. Or just pull hard with your hand.